# Facebook login only working for one user on which account I have created facebook business app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, facebook-login

**Facebook login only working for one account** only **for developer account** on **I have created Facebook business app.**

```
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login';

  const responseFacebook = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }

<FacebookLogin
              appId='here-is-my-facebook-app-id'
              autoLoad={true}
              fields='name,email,picture'
              scope='public_profile,user_friends'
              callback={responseFacebook}
              icon='fa-facebook'
            />
```

How I can use same app for all users facebook login.

Comment: You will need to switch the app mode from Development to Live, it's in your Facebook login app of the Facebook developer console

Comment: Do you solve this issue? I have the same situation. App i already in live mode.

Comment: In development you have to add user from developer console then new added user also will be able to login with facebook